# Puppet configuration version is different for the noop and apply

Tags: puppet

I have few `puppet` modules and I have already applied them. But the problem is, even though I have applied, the puppet is still forcing me with the changes, that means puppet still shows the differences that is going to be applied (even after it is being applied)

I did a puppet noop:

```
puppet agent -vt  --noop
```

And it gives the following output:

```
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Applying configuration version '1632762925'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Apim_common/Exec[stop-server]/returns: current_value 'notrun', should be ['0'] (noop) (corrective)
Info: /Stage[main]/Apim_common/Exec[stop-server]: Scheduling refresh of Exec[delete-pack]
Notice: /Stage[main]/Apim_common/Exec[delete-pack]: Would have triggered 'refresh' from 1 event
Notice: /Stage[main]/Apim_common/Exec[unzip-update]/returns: current_value 'notrun', should be ['0'] (noop) (corrective)
Notice: Class[Apim_common]: Would have triggered 'refresh' from 3 events
Notice: /Stage[main]/Monitoring/Exec[Restart awslogsd service]/returns: current_value 'notrun', should be ['0'] (noop) (corrective)
Notice: Class[Monitoring]: Would have triggered 'refresh' from 1 event
Notice: Stage[main]: Would have triggered 'refresh' from 2 events
Notice: Applied catalog in 5.70 seconds
```

And then I did a puppet apply:

```
puppet agent -vt
```

```
Info: Using environment 'test'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Caching catalog for amway-320-test-api-analytics-worker-1-i-00d684727d24cc360.intranet.local
Info: Applying configuration version '1632762946'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Apim_common/Exec[stop-server]/returns: executed successfully (corrective)
Info: /Stage[main]/Apim_common/Exec[stop-server]: Scheduling refresh of Exec[delete-pack]
Notice: /Stage[main]/Apim_common/Exec[delete-pack]: Triggered 'refresh' from 1 event
Notice: /Stage[main]/Apim_common/Exec[unzip-update]/returns: executed successfully (corrective)
Notice: /Stage[main]/Monitoring/Exec[Restart awslogsd service]/returns: executed successfully (corrective)
Notice: /Stage[main]/Apim_analytics_worker/File[/mnt/apim_analytics_worker/test-analytics-3.2.0/conf/worker/deployment.yaml]/content: 
--- /mnt/apim_analytics_worker/testam-analytics-3.2.0/conf/worker/deployment.yaml   2021-05-18 02:13:05.000000000 -0400
+++ /tmp/puppet-file20210927-468-19w731k    2021-09-27 13:15:56.250247257 -0400
@@ -14,16 +14,16 @@
 #   limitations under the License.
 ################################################################################
 
-  # Carbon Configuration Parameters
+# Carbon Configuration Parameters
 test.carbon:
   type: test-apim-analytics
-    # value to uniquely identify a server
+  # value to uniquely identify a server
   id: test-am-analytics
.
.
.
```

And everytime I do a `puppet agent -vt`, it is producing this output over and over, which it shouldn't as the changes are already being applied. I tried removing the `cache` directory in `/opt/puppet/...` directory but still no luck.

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Could you post your code, please?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a lot of `Exec` resources.  That's not wrong *per se*, but it has bad code smell.

It looks like you are managing some things via `Exec`s that might be better modeled as `Service` resources (and maybe better set up as *bona fide* system services, too, which is a separate question).  There may be other things that would be better managed as `File`s or `Package`s.

Where you do use an `Exec`, you should either make it `refreshonly` or give it an appropriate `unless`, `onlyif`, or `creates` parameter, or both, to establish criteria for whether its command will run.  Puppet does not track whether the `Exec` was synced on some earlier run, and it wouldn't matter if it did because having been synced on an earlier run does not necessarily mean that it should not be synced again.

Comment: I am actually handling the said file/s using the `file` module in puppet. That is what is strange. Puppet version is `7.10.0`

Comment: Ok, @JananathBanuka, if the file was what you wanted to focus on then you should have said so.  But all I can say is that if Puppet successfully applies identical changes to that file on every run then something else -- either another resource or something outside Puppet's scope -- must be modifying it, too.  It's just a change in comment indentation, so perhaps it is being reformatted by the application?  On the other hand, `Exec[unzip-update]` looks suspicious in this regard -- could it be overwriting the file with a differently formatted version?